# Something strange in Latticeplot

Tags: r, lattice

Basic Information of my Laptop:

```
SO: Windows 7 x64
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) -- "Frisbee Sailing"
```

Problem:

When i run the following code:

```
x <- rnorm (100)
z <- z + rnorm(100)
f <- gl(2,50,labels =c("Groups 1" , "Groups 2"))
xyplot (z ~ x | f,
    panel = function (x, z, ...) {
      panel.xyplot(x,z, ...)
      panel.abline(h = median(z),
                   lty=2
                   )
    })
```

What I obtain is no error on console but not graph either, instead of the graph receive two empty graph boxes with inside this error:

```
 "error using packet 2, argument "z" in missing, with no defaults"
```

But in the enviroment "z" exist and it is valid!

If I run the script with y instead of z this run as intended, two graph are plotted one aside another(the code works). What is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Panel functions are passed coordinates `x` and `y`, from the notation `y ~ x`. Hence you write your panel function in terms of those arguments, not the names of your own data objects passed to those arguments. Then it works:

```
x <- rnorm (100)
z <- x + rnorm(100)
f <- gl(2,50,labels =c("Groups 1" , "Groups 2"))
df <- data.frame(x = x, z = z, f = f) ## I prefer objects in data frames
xyplot (z ~ x | f, data = df,
    panel = function (x, y, ...) {
      panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
      panel.abline(h = median(y),
                   lty=2
                   )
    })
```

Comment: This is right, and good explanation. What's a little surprising, to my mind, is that you can set `panel = function(x, y=y, ...)` **or** `panel = function(x, y=z, ...)`, and both work equally well. I wouldn't have expected the second one to work, yet it does: a `browser()` call placed inside the supplied panel function even finds a variable `y` of the correct length. Curious what's going on here.

Comment: @Josh, `function(x, y=y, ...)` only works since lattice passes `y`  explicitly and so the default is never used.   Had the default been used it would have been a circular reference and failed. Regarding `function(x, y = z, ...)` `z` is similarly never used.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck -- OK, of course. The user supplies `panel=` with a function **definition**, which is in turn **called** by some part `xyplot()`, and that call overrides any default values in the definition. Thanks for helping me to see that.